# Hyperlink Colour or Underline

Tags: feature-request

I find it very hard (verging on impossible) to tell if there is a link in the text of questions on Salesforce Exchange.

Would it be possible to either:

a) increase the contrast of the link colour vs the text colour

or

b) add an underline like in the old days...

Thoughts?

Comment: Am in total agreement with you on increasing the contrast for hyperlinks! I have a visual impairment that makes it incredibly difficult at times to notice the links and sometimes miss them! It's really VERY POOR UI design IMO!

Answer (score 3):

This entire site is driven by CSS, so it's entirely possible that it *could* be changed. However, someone from higher up than I would have to request a change from whoever does the theme. However for your own personal benefit, you could install an Extension if you're in Chrome or Firefox to modify the CSS for this site. As an example, I installed [User CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb), then added a quick style in order to make the change I wanted to. You can also do this without an extension (check your browser's online manual), but I find an extension is much easier to make changes on the fly. Here's an image of me altering the links so they are red:

[image: Site with red links enabled]

---

Of course, a better solution would be to change the `a:visited` style so that it's much lighter and/or underlined and/or somehow not looking like the plain text. The contrast is visible when your screen is very bright and there's not a lot of extra light, but I totally agree that it needs to be updated to be more functional than it is now.

Comment: How and to whom does this get raised, such that it could be changed?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Maybe you know? I'm just a user.

Comment: why are you not an Moderator?

Comment: @Robs (a) being a moderator would take time away from me answering questions, (b) being a moderator has a different skill set requirement that I likely don't possess, and (c) moderator positions are limited, so by being one, I'd take up a precious slot that could be done by someone with the correct skill set.

Comment: Sounds like a very reasonable set of reasons :)

Comment: "just a user". THE user.